# Radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nz^{n^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

> Find the radius of convergence of the power series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nz^{n^2}$$ where , $a_0=1$ and $a_n=\frac{a_{n-1}}{3^n}$.

***My Work :***

We, have, $$\frac{a_1}{a_0}.\frac{a_2}{a_1}...\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}=\frac{1}{3}.\frac{1}{3^2}...\frac{1}{3^n}$$

$$\implies a_n=3^{-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$$

Now put $n^2=p$. Then the series becomes , $$\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}a_pz^p$$ where, $a_p=3^{\frac{p+\sqrt {p}}{2}}$.

Now $$\left|\frac{a_{p+1}}{a_p}\right|\to \frac{1}{\sqrt 3} \text{ as } p\to \infty$$

So , radius of convergence is $\sqrt 3$.

I think my answer is correct..But I want to know does there any other trick so that we can find the radius of convergence without finding $a_n$ explicitly ?

Please help...

Comment: You **cannot** substitute $n^2=p$ this way, you get an entirely different series. The original one is $\frac z3+\frac{z^4}{27}+\frac{z^9}{729}+...$ while what you obtain after substitution is $\frac z3+\frac{z^2}{3^{1+\frac{\sqrt2}2}}+\frac{z^3}{3^{\frac{3+\sqrt3}2}}+...$

Comment: Ohh!!..So how we find ?

Comment: Do you know convergence criteria of power series?

Comment: OK just try to divide without substitution, $\left|\frac{f_{n+1}}{f_n}\right|$ where $f_n=a_nz^{n^2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to use Cauchy-Hadamard theorem, you would get Radius too.

So as you mentoined let $a_n = 3^{-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}} = 3^{-\frac{n^2}{2}}3^{-n}3^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ . So radius is now:
$$
1/R = \limsup_{n \to \infty} \big|a_n\big|^{\frac{1}{n^2}} = \limsup_{n \to \infty} \Big| 3^{-\frac{n^2}{2}}3^{-n}3^{-\frac{1}{2}} \Big|^{\frac{1}{n^2}} = 3^{-\frac{1}{2}}
$$

So the radius of convergence should be: $ R = \sqrt{3} $

Comment: Well except in more detail you have $\sum a_nz^{n^2}=\sum b_nz^n$ where $b_{n^2}$ is $a_n$ and all other $b$'s are zero, and then you can apply the above to $b_n$...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider the terms of the sequence
$$
\frac{z^{n^2}}{\sqrt3^{\,n^2+n}}=\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt3^{1+\frac1n}}\right)^{n^2}
$$
Think ratio test, or compare with
$$
\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt3^{1+\frac1n}}\right)^n
$$
For $z\lt\sqrt3$ and $z\gt\sqrt3$.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, if $\sum_n b_nz^n$ is a power series, then there is an explicit formula for the radius of convergence: $$R = \frac{1}{\limsup_n |b_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}}$$ In this case we have that $b_{n^2}=a_n=3^{-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$. Hence $b_{n^2}^{\frac{1}{n^2}}=3^{-\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{1}{n})}$. Thus, substituting $k$ for $n^2$, we have that

$|b_k|^{-\frac{1}{k}} = \left\{
 \begin{array}{}
    3^{-\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}})} & : k \text{ is a perfect square}\\
    0 & : \text{ otherwise}
  \end{array} \right.$

It follows that $\limsup_k |b_k|^{\frac{1}{k}}=3^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, which gives $R=\sqrt{3}$.